# can't install smach_viewer on ros melodic

Tags: ros

I tried installing smach on ROS Melodic with the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-smach ros-melodic-smach-ros ros-melodic-executive-smach ros-melodic-smach-viewer
```

from the book i'm reading ROS Robotics Projects by Ramkumar Gandhinathan, Lentin Joseph. while the other packages got installed the smach_viewer package gave a 404 error. After checking the package on this link i found out that some of the deb files were missing. please how do i solve this problem.

this is the error i'm getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
python3-click python3-colorama
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libepoxy-dev libgtk-3-dev
libxkbcommon-dev libxtst-dev python-gi-cairo wayland-protocols
x11proto-record-dev
Suggested packages:
libgtk-3-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libepoxy-dev libgtk-3-dev
libxkbcommon-dev libxtst-dev python-gi-cairo ros-melodic-smach-viewer
wayland-protocols x11proto-record-dev
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 83.6 kB/1,551 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-smach-viewer amd64 3.0.0-1bionic.20210414.224955
404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-smach-viewer/ros-melodic-smach-viewer_3.0.0-1bionic.20210414.224955_amd64.deb  
404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

please can anyone help me solve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a standard apt problem. You need to make sure to run an `apt-get update` soon before you run `apt-get install ...` to make sure that you have the latest index of packages. If new versions have been released since you last did an update it will fail to find the packages with the 404 error you are seeing.